# Build vs. Buy & Integrate - How do YOU make the decision?

Tags: estimation

I've seen a lot of questions and discussions about build vs. buy, but most stick with the simplistic approach that you can simply do one or the other. Most of the time you have to either buy and integrate or build yourself. Either way you're in for some work.

In the next 30-60 days I NEED to implement a couple managerial projects to keep everyone from ripping their hair out and killing each other. The largest of which is a ticketing system (emails, support requests, self service, etc.).

There is no shortage of options but at the end of the day we'll have to buy whatever we decide to use, add all our clients and their users and make sure we keep things in sync over time. We'll also have to provide a single sign-on and do some design work to make it all look like we built it from scratch.

If we build we get to skip the integration pain points, albeit with a limited (but focused) feature set.

What do you typically analyze while making a decision like this? If it better to have 4-5 systems that do a very specific job well, or one monolithic system that does everything?

Comment: Duplicate:? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233346/to-buy-or-to-build-that-is-the-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've identified a key issue - when you buy you still have work to do, and potentially lots of it. Having said that my overall leaning every time is towards buy. Writing code is hard, debugging code is much harder - when you buy, you're not just buying the code/application you're buying the fact that it works - the latter is 90% of the benefit.

However, as your needs are pretty common, why not go with open source. This has two stand out benefits.

1) As you have access to the source, you can bend it to your will - ie no need to lash single sign on over the top of an existing system. Tailor the login modules to use your already existing infrastructure, therefore no need to keep things in sync, time savings, clean approach etc etc. Much open source acknowledges the real world by componentising (?) those aspects which are environement specific anyway. They're often DB/Identity agnostic.

2) If you choose wisely you will have a ready band of top tech staff who already understand the system ready to help - the only problem is they don't work for you (yet!).

My advice would be pick one of your easy targets - the ticketing system seems like the one, analyse whats out there that in the open source world that meets most/all of your needs. Evaluate and put out a request on [Rent A Coder](http://www.rentacoder.com/RentACoder/DotNet/default.aspx) for any changes that are required. Sit back and await the results, which are hopefully excellent. You've lost a little time, and gained a lot of experience.

Open source does not equal Linux/Unix - lots of good stuff for .Net out there too.

Answer (score 0):

One system is better for the following:

- One data repository(i.e. the Database)
  Easy way to link each system together, do cross referencing.  No need to build intermediate importer/exporters/sync-ers
- Allows for single log in.  This is very useful in businesses to make sure everyone know where to find the right information.  So more "what was the site for the bug tracking again..."  Not everyone will use all the tools the majority of the time, and they *will* forget how to access and even use.
- Everything has the same look and feel
  Saves on training
- Maintenance is cheaper.  Everything is the same to update.  Admins dont have to specialize in hear separate system.

But... obviously you're stuck with what you buy.  Make sure to get a system if you can that you can build your own addins for, to match it to your busienss' model.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously "it depends." My general rule is that if it's internal we buy it and integrate if required. Our corporate sys admin has a support line to someone external to our organization if she has issues and it isn't a huge project burdening our developers.

If it's part of a product I'm shipping, I build it or take bits of source as needed from open source libraries. There's nothing worse than someone else's black box code breaking your product. The fewer the dependencies in a shipping product the better, IMHO.

I'd lean toward buy for a support product like you mention. The good ones offer great integration points to shared authentication systems, user facing theming, and probably a boatload of features your customer service team hasn't realized they want/need yet.

But, what to analyze. The biggest thing for me when it comes to 'managerial' projects like this is opportunity cost. What else could my team be working on that will make our company significantly more money, get us more customers, etc? Of course these projects have some positive impact on the bottom line, but nothing compared to new products, improved products, etc. How long over time, including maintenance, will developers/pm's/testers spend on this managerial project? If you buy, integration points don't change often, but if you build, your customers (in house people) will be asking for new features constantly and you'll be in the position to maintain this project for the rest of your tenure.

Answer (score 0):

Buy? What is this buy of which you speak, stranger?

Seriously, I haven't had to buy a piece of software for my own projects for a long long time. All my development tools are free, all my third-party libraries are free (not GPL). Even my OS is free. I have to pay for Windows for testing purposes but the majority of work uses tools that are cross-platform.

Anything that requires code not immediately available from free tools or libraries, I either write from scratch (all the algorithms are available for free on the web) or use my (huge since I'm so old) snippet library which I've been adding source code to for many years.

It's almost always quicker to buy ("obtain") than build unless the bought stuff is so crappy that integration is a nightmare. This can be mitigated by avoiding the latest whizz-bang stuff from suppliers that have little track record.

Answer (score 0):

The more 'standard' your requirements, the better buying fits (Or to put it another way, don't reinvent the wheel).  Conversely, the more unique your requirements the more you might consider building.

You quite rightly point out that even when buying there tends to be some customisation.  Bear in mind that any customisation will cost you at each upgrade/patching time.  I suggest that if your requirements are close to the business model supported by one of the tools you might buy that you serious consider realigning the business process to the vendors standard.  If this is not possible ask if you are buying the correct tool.

I would suggest that if someone suggests building it for cost reasons run screaming.  In my experience the cost of buying is well known and the cost of build is well hidden.  Remember that you will be making a decision to keep coding for the life of the App (average of 7 years for a business app) but may be considering only the initial development cost when deciding between buy and build.

I have a strong preference for a single monolithic database but sometimes this is not workable.  More important is to have a 'single source of the truth'; if you have multiple databases holding like data, pick one as the authoritative source of a given piece of data and have a process to maintain all others in agreement with that source.  Preferable this will be automatic.

Answer (score 0):

The monolithic system that does everything is the the [Raison d'être](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raison_d%27%C3%AAtre) for so many Enterprise applications.  What I've found, however, is that if you're not willing to pay a buttload of money, you're going to have integration issues.

The 'best' solution is quite subjective, and any answer is as right as it is wrong, but if I were king, I'd probably go with the entrenched open source solution where it fit, and wrap web services around the items that needed to talk to each other.  If I were king.

As a tangential point, there are free ticketing systems like [RT](http://bestpractical.com/rt/) (et. al.) that you need not worry about buying.